# Can we use Expanded/ Flexible widget in Stack for creating right head arrow in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need a flexible right arrow head so that it is adjustable according to the screen size which is possible using Expanded/Flexible widget, But with Stack Widget i'm not able to use Expanded/Flexible Widget...

```
ListView(
  children: ListTile.divideTiles(
    context: context,
    tiles: [
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(240.0, 189.0, 0.00, 0.00),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black,)),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100.00, 200.0, 0.0, 0.00),
                width: 150.0,
                height: 1.0,
                color: Colors.black,),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ).toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Stack widget, every widget in the children of Stack widget will display like a layer. So instead of using Expended or Flexible as a child of Stack, use Container widget then add Expanded or Flexible as children.

```html
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

By the way, if you want to add an icon at a corner or every where on the screen, use Positioned widget instead.